# Javascript: Call function after 10 seconds, then each 1 minute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario:

I have a javascript ajax function `loadCars()` that needs to be called after the page loads in 10 seconds, and then every 60 seconds.

The below is what I have tried so far:

```
setTimeout(function(){setInterval(function(){loadCars()}, 60000)}, 10000);
```

What is happening is that the function is being called after 10 seconds but never again, what am I missing?

Comment: If by "didn't work as expected" you mean it didn't call it after 10 seconds, but did after 70, 130 etc, just add an extra `loadCars();` directly before `setInterval`.  If that's not what you mean, can you explain further "didn't work as expected"

Comment: Consider hooking on certain events (like page finished rendering) rather than fixed timings (10 sec delay)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Actually the exact opposite happened, It called the function after 10 seconds and never again

Comment: downvoter, can you please explain??

Comment: @brso05 I am not worried mate, but usually when I downvote a question, I explain why

Comment: @AliIssa I agree anytime you downvote you should say why but some people just don't get it...

Comment: I didn't DV, but can see why someone might under "unclear" as the problem isn't fully documented until the comments.  I'm still having trouble thinking that it's behaving in the way you've described!

Comment: @brso05 I disagree - voting (both up and down) is [intentionally anonymous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85529/is-down-voting-supposed-to-be-anonymous).  If you had to comment every time you downvoted, there would be a lot less of it going on :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you for your comment, I fixed the question format a little bit better now?

Comment: @AliIssa Yeah - it's clear now.  But I still don't get why it would do it after 10 then no more :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe I disagree...you should say why so the user has a chance to fix the problem if you don't say why then there would be a lot more bad answers and questions out there that still need fixing...

Comment: @JamesThorpe this is my problem and why I asked the question here :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `loadCars` on `setTimeout` and on `setInterval`.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('first 10 secs');
    // loadCars();
  
    setInterval(function() {
          console.log('60 secs has passed');
          // loadCars();
    }, 60000);

}, 10000);
console.log('page loaded');
```

Comment: setInterval is bad practise, it doesnt wait for the function to finish executing

Comment: I doesn't wrote that setInterval is a good practice. I just answered the question, fixed the code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the answers given because they use setInterval or don't wait for the ajax call to be finished. IMO your should set a new timeout only when the function loadcars (and the ajax call) has finished.

**Example:**

```
function loadCars () {
  // ajax call happens here
  $.ajax()
    .then(function(){
      // call the function here
      setTimeout(function(){
        loadCars();
      // wait a minute after you recieved the data
      }, 60000)
    })
}

// wait 10 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  loadCars();
}, 10000)
```

The advantage if this is that it will only start setting a new timeout when the HTTP request is finished and prevent the function from getting out of sync. If you use setinterval in combination with an ajax call then the next ajax call will happen in 60 seconds even if the current one is delayed for 10 seconds (and you don't want that).

Comment: True, but (in your example) you do not wait for request to finish.

Comment: @brso05 Well, they don't consider that the ajax call can be delayed either

Comment: Can you really use `$.ajax().then()`?

Comment: @brso05 succes() is deprecated, and then will also fire on fail so I still think this is better

Comment: @brso05 You are talking about the paramater which is not deprectated, but it's nicer to stick with the new standards and use done() instead of success(). Anyway, off-topic

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setTimeout(loadCars, 60000)` in your `loadCars()` method that way you call it once initially with `setTimeout` 10 seconds then from that point it sets a timeout for 1 minute out every time it executes...

```
function loadCars()
{
    //code
    setTimeout(loadCars, 60000);
}

setTimeout(loadCars, 10000);
```

If you want the next timeout to be scheduled only after `ajax` call is completed then either make a synchronus `ajax` call or put the `setTimeout()` in your `success` callback of your `ajax` call...The latter being the better option.

Comment: Synchronous ajax is best avoided (outside webworkers).  The [specification warns](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) that it is in the process of being removed, indeed Chrome (not sure of other browsers) already logs the warning as recommended

Comment: @JamesThorpe you are correct that is why I provided a second(better option) putting it in the `success` callback function.

Comment: Indeed.  But I would have put the recommended/better option first :)

Answer (score 1):

To get more control over timings and function calls you could specify them all this way:

```js
function loadCars() {
    $('#log').append('Cars loaded<br />');
};
function loadManufacturers() {
    $('#log').append('Manufacturers loaded<br />');
};
function loadCustomers() {
    $('#log').append('Customers loaded<br />');
};
function loadContent(delays, functions) {
    if (functions.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            functions.pop()();
            loadContent(delays, functions);
        }, delays.pop());
    };
};
loadContent([3000, 2000, 1000], [loadCars, loadManufacturers, loadCustomers]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="log"></p>
```

[Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/t4y7szzg/)