# Call javascript function first in 10 seconds then every 25 seconds [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "someurl",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          //Some code
        }
    });
}, 25 * 1000);
```

The above code works calling to the ajax method every 25 seconds. But for the first time I need it to call it in 10 seconds and then every 25 seconds.

So I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029757/javascript-call-function-after-10-seconds-then-each-1-minute)

and changed my code to something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "someurl",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              //Some code
            }
        });
    }, 25 * 1000);
}, 10 * 1000);
```

But it still doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What's your question? (That code looks fine at first glance.)

Comment: I think the issue is the first execution does not call until after the first interval returns?

Comment: Yes, the ajax method is called only after 25 seconds.

Comment: Probably 35 seconds, actually. Answers all flooded in quickly. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    function doit() {
        console.log("HERE");
    }
    doit(); // It's already been 10 seconds, so run it now
    setInterval(doit, 25 * 1000); // Run it every 25 seconds from here on out
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 0):

Since `setInterval` doesn’t fire its callback immediately, you’ll need to do that manually before starting the second timer:

```
function sendRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "someurl",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          //Some code
        }
    });
}

setTimeout(function() {
    sendRequest();
    setInterval(sendRequest, 25 * 1000);
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: Ha, beat me by 30 seconds. :-)